# Cactus and Succulent in the same pot

Tags: cactus, succulents

I am looking to plant several cacti and succulents together in a single pot.  Several of the plants will include a grafted "moon" cactus and a succulent "Eceveria Mazarine" there may be one or two similar plants added additionally.

I have read the cactus cannot deal with direct sunlight since the "scion" cactus on top lacks chlorophyl so it needs indirect sunlight.  Where as succulents prefer direct sunlight.  Both plants require soil which drains quickly.

As for the light the plants will be placed indoors behind paper blinds in a relatively sunny window which does not let any direct sunlight in.

As for the soil I plan to use regular potting soil will a small amount of sand I have collected from near the oceanfront added to the soil, then gravel as a top layer.

Are these plants compatible together?  and are the lighting and soil conditions adequate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of sand in the mix I would recommend adding chicken grit or similar small crushed rock.  Sand will wash out of the soil mix or compact into a layer depending on the type of sand.

One of the plants will do much better than the others and will need to be carefully pinched back. As I have never had any long term success with the grafted cactus I believe the succulent will do better.

With the reduced light levels you will see some [etiolation](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/14667/what-is-etiolation) but cutting back should be sufficient to keep things in shape.