# Can I cut the top off a drooping aloe plant?

Tags: houseplants, succulents, light, aloe

I inherited this horrible aloe plant from an old roommate. It was living in a tall, skinny Tupperware in a dark corner of the kitchen, where it got knocked over and stepped on more than once. From reading around, I gather it grew tall like this because of low light? I put it in a bigger pot, transplanted one of its several babies, and put it in a sunny windowsill. I've read that it's possible to cut the top off a plant like this and propagate it. My question is this: what would happen to the bottom part if I did that? Would it survive? Would it grow to not be horrifically ugly?

[image]

Answer (score 9):

The damaged leaves will not heal, and the weakened narrow portion of stem will remain that way. It can grow from the end, though, and that can be healthy. It was obviously suffering from [etiolation.](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/14667/what-is-etiolation) I think the best method of action starts with repotting the aloe. Use a free draining cactus mix, and a free draining pot. You can repot the pups in separate containers (don't worry, it should produce more). The idea is that although the old growth will never look better than it does now (you could end up with a very  healthy new end on it though), the stem will root when exposed to soil. This is the method I have used for quite some time for my personal aloes, when the stem gets long [(1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wEww3.jpg),
 [(2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DQoCF.jpg) (also useful for salvaging badly damaged specimens like yours, in the interest of continuing growth on the original stem).

- Remove the plant from the pot, and loosely shake the mix from the roots.
- There should be a portion of stem extending into the mix, which is what the roots grow from. Remove a section of this root bearing stem, leaving only about an inch of stem that still has roots.
- Remember how much stem you removed, and go up the stem, stripping leaves from the stem to match the distance.
- You can let the plant dry here, if you're afraid of rot (I usually plant right away).
- Place some mix into the bottom of the container, and place the stem all the way to the bottom. Place more mix around the stem, up to 1/2" from the container rim, or from the lowest remaining leaves (whichever comes first). Firm it well, so that the whole stem will remain in contact with the mix.
- Water it in. From here until it is actively growing, only let the top inch of mix dry between thorough waterings, and make sure it drains well. Do not fertilize
- Keep it in warm (at least 65 degrees Fahrenheit) areas, outdoors whenever possible (but avoid direct sun).
- Make sure it gets plenty of light. Sunlight is best, but needs to be introduced slowly, as aloes sunburn very easily and the damage is permanent. But even a shady spot outdoors is often brighter than artificial house lighting.

Here's a similar plant, needing to be lowered.
[image]

After lowering. 
[image]

In a month or so, it will have rooted into the mix and started growing. This new growth should be robust and heavy, so the frail stem may need support. After a year of growth, repeat the process. Eventually you will have healthy, new growth from the top to the bottom. I do this regularly, to maintain stem length on my aloes. Feel free to ask for more information.

Edit: I'm adding a picture of the same plant now, several months after treatment. Note how much stronger it is:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This aloe is actually or was mature enough to do some powerful medicine. Needs way more light. Less watering. Less fertilizer. Take out that baby aloe and replant into a tiny pot. Cut dead leaves back to their base. Once aloe gets leaves 2 to 3" in width they are amazing with stopping infection and healing cuts. They sure stick as well but great stuff. You are watering too much and I'll bet too much fertilizer, yes? No?

Also you are probably using tap water? Too many salts from either or both fertilizer and/or tap water. Use bottled water and only water when very very dry. Repot in new potting soil after washing, scrubbing the salts out of this pot. Clay is good. Raise the bottom off that saucer using thin tiles to enhance drainage.  Don't water but once every other week once this plant and the baby aloe are established.

Just because this plant looks awful it is not genetic!  This guy has a mature root system and can become...as well as the little aloes, big gorgeous plants.  Use Osmocote 14-14-14 only ONCE PER YEAR.  Don't fertilize if you've already been fertilizing for at least 6 months.

Get him in a south facing window out of direct sunlight acclimating him little by little to full sunlight through the window.  If you have a covered porch, put him out on the porch during the summers...covered porch not direct sunlight.  Always potting soil.  Read other answers about succulents and potting procedures...he is only ugly because no one appreciated this guy's worth!!  [image: cuts]

This is my first try to use computer graphics.  So ugh what a lot of work to figure out!!  Need more 'cuts' let me know.  Sooner rather than later.  Gees.  I can't believe how UN user friendly these apps have become...

Comment: Thanks!

It's actually hardly been watered over the last few months, but I guess the damage was probably already done. Also, it's never been fertilized since arriving in our possession (about a year ago?), but again, no idea who did what to it before that.

It's currently in an east-facing window that gets direct sun in the morning. Will that work? Because of how my apartment is set up, I have no south-facing windows.

Will the main plant get a healthier appearance on its own if I treat it better? Or should I try to cut/propagate it at all?

Comment: This plant most certainly will be able to revive.  East window will work but do you have a covered patio?  I'd cut off all the dead parts of leaves and the leaves that have no hope.  You could propagate a few of those tips and heck you have baby aloes already to plant in their own TINY pot. If there are broken leaves cut off the tips (make a very acute angle that will look more natural) and that will take weight off to allow the leave to pop up again.  As your plant gets more turgid from health the leaves will be strong enough to hold their own weight.  A little bit of extended release OSMOCOT

Comment: Do not cut the large plant from the top at all.  For instance, that leaf on the LEFT third one down that is bent.  Cut that right below that bend beginning at the strippling and upwards to a point...the leaf on the right first one from the top, I'd cut from the side at least an inch down into the healthy part to end with a sharpish tip. Scissors always point the same direction as the leaf. Try to keep the cut part underneath allowing the healthy part to be able to receive the most sun.  Do not worry about the oozing.  Do a leaf per day not the whole plant.  If you have any owieees glop some on

Comment: @stormy Why "not cut the large plant from the top at all"? It's an easy propagation method.

Comment: @stormy I have downvoted this "answer" because you assume the OP did fertilize, only then ask about fertilizing, then you get the info that the OP didn't fertilize, you answer half of the questions the OP had, you write a lot about things the OP didn't ask, and yes, they are related to gardening, but then all posts on this site are about gardening. You say always to use potting soil, but I have seen all Aloe planted in garden soil in India and they all look well. You say never to use tap water, but you don't know where the OP lives and what kind of tap water he/she has.

Comment: @stormy I have seen some of your answers getting negative score, but I assure you that if it was me, I'd left a note like this, explaining why. I also appreciate the fact that you try to salvage every plant, so please, go on answering questions on this site and I bet you'll be much appreciated for doing it more on-topic.

Comment: @Alina  You are sweet...I am the sort of  person that actually causes negative reactions.  I am fine with who I am but I still feel that those that are able to willy nilly vote me down should have to explain WHY.  I do know I will never be the popular person.  Because I don't TRY that hard to be popular and I know there is no way to be me and please everyone.  So I choose to be me...too much dang energy to try to please everyone!!  Grins.  Sure stirs up great conversations which I believe is healthy and exciting.  Jus' can't hep mesef.  I'm fine with how I do things and as I see that I am able

Comment: ...to make small changes to become more a part of the herd I do so.  And we all know that these people with questions know not what to even ask!  So if I see that a pot is full of garden soil, I will bring that up...more often than not I am right on and when I am not they got a bit more than they expected which is wrong...WHY?  My goal is to identify the real problem not just answer the question and help the OP to be successful.  One plant at a time, grins.  Thank you for the kind words of support.  I've got a very thick skin but see easy fixes to make this site work better for all.

Comment: The reason I disagree and I should have made that more clear is that the apical bud on this plant should stay right where it is with the healthier leaves.    Aloe is not the type of plant that will get bushier or send the energy down to the lateral bud cause there aren't any!  Through our conversations I've discovered more than what they imagined telling; about their tap water, bottled water...planting anything in garden soil put into a pot you should know by now that I KNOW that is a no no...and if you've not noticed others have changed their tune and information since I've been here, grins!!

Comment: ...and I love to find out how other countries treat their municipal waters.  Ours in America is scary and shameful.  Period.   Every dang family has to have a black sheep...keeps things interesting.  Lame rationalization, I know.  Seriously wasn't trying to be the obstinate one, didn't think I was but by now it is sort of obvious...huggs!