# Stalk on healthy aloe plant getting too long

Tags: houseplants, plant-health, pruning, aloe

I have a healthy aloe plant whose stalk is getting so long that it’s beginning to bend over. What’s the best solution here? To repot in a larger pot so I can plant it lower? Or should I just stake it? Should I cut the stalk down a bit (knowing that it will take some time for the roots to return)? [image: aloe plant]

Comment: [Related.](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/31419/can-i-cut-the-top-off-a-drooping-aloe-plant)

Answer (score 1):

It really looks like it's time to repot it. Little bigger pot, and pot it deeper. Don't cut the stalk it most likely will not re-root itself, it'll just die!