# Aloe plant needs rescuing

Tags: aloe

[image]

I just had my kitchen repainted and while moving my adopted aloe plant back to its sunny south facing spot on the kitchen window sill his long stem broke. Well it really just creaked, not actual snapping... (has my lack of plant knowledge come through loudly enough?)

Is the big part done for? I know the little guy is good where he is. And will probably grow better with big brother making a mess of the pot.

Do I just break/cut it off? Can I stick that in another pot and will it grow?

Anything I can do with the leaves if the big guy is a goner?

P.s. the snail is just a shell we picked up hiking in Vermont.

Comment: [My answer on a closely related question](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/a/31455/419). If this answers your question, we can close it as a duplicate.