# Are these succulent plants Sempervivum?

Tags: identification, houseplants, succulents, container-gardening

I have these succulents and I don't know their name. The big one on the left is Haworthia attenuata, but the small ones are a mystery to me. Usually their leaves are curved upwards, but now are downwards because of the lack of light. I think they might be a species of Sempervivum, although I don't know which one.
[image]

Below are the upper leaves of Haworthia
[image]

Comment: I would also think some _Sempervivum_ but biological convergence sucks on such plant forms.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is this succulent plant bought from a botanical garden?](http://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/11214/what-is-this-succulent-plant-bought-from-a-botanical-garden)

Comment: There are quite a few of this species that look so similar.  I was thinking Haworthia fasciata and I'll bet you have the label...

Comment: Yes, stormy, the one on the left had a label as Haworthia fasciata. However, this label is incorrect, since H. fasciata has smooth upper leaves. My plant, although it cannot be seen in the picture, has rugged white dots on the upper side of the leaves, somewhat similar to H. attenuata. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haworthia_attenuata I will add a picture to this post, since I don't know how to upload one in a comment. My question was about the small ones on the right that only had a label as "Succulent mix", just like the Sedum morganianum that was also labeled as "Succulent mix".

Comment: You understand plants, obviously!  Send a picture of your whole pot if you want.  I love these baby succulents.  But then they grow up and start producing babies of their own.  This is a short term pot situation.  In 6 months that stone mulch will be covered.  Have you seen the framed 'succulent' pictures?  Hanging on a wall, or becoming the roof covering on house boats?  So beautiful.  Then you can use the babies of the succulents to make gifts for friends.  Seriously beautiful, succulent artwork! psst...Just copy and paste the link to include within the comments..

Comment: The Haworthia is H. pumila not H. attenuata

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This would appear to be [*Sempervivum tectorum* (common houseleek)](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sempervivum_tectorum). That is an arrangement of matured rosettes, and not the natural growth habit of the plant. Another name for it is hens and chicks.

[image]