# What is this flower-like succulent with hair on the tips?

Tags: identification, succulents

Could you please identify succulent in the following picture? I like its strange symmetry. What is its hardiness zone? Would it survive the coldness of zone 5, if left outdoors in the winter, while keeping it in its current container and arrangement?

[image: Succulent arrangement]

This question is based on [another (closed) question](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/35386/please-id-succulents-and-their-hardiness-zone-to-survive-winter).

The plant in the question linked to in a comment (that claims that the two questions are duplicates) doesn't look like the plant from this question. They may be the same genus or species, but the point is to discover the exact, or approximate, variant or cultivar.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is this succulent plant bought from a botanical garden?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/11214/what-is-this-succulent-plant-bought-from-a-botanical-garden)

Comment: @J. The plant in the question you linked to doesn't look like the plant from this question. They may be the same genus or species, but the point is to discover the exact, or approximate, variant or cultivar.

Comment: Well.. out of the 400+ cultivars of Sempervivum tectorum alone, and the high conditional variability in appearance of each one, it is actually not possible to pinpoint an exact cultivar ID. But yeah I accidentally used the wrong link there. The one I linked to showed a semp in poor health, and etiolated, about to flower.

Comment: For all practical purposes (for an average reader) it is sufficient to find an approximate cultivar, but just species is not enough, in this case.

Comment: That's interesting.. an approximate cultivar? I'm not sure I follow. Were you looking to make a nametag for the plant?

Comment: I think genus is enough. One go to the shop and then look for species and cultivars according preferences.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi Then we could say it is enough to say that it is a plant, and one can go and shop. ;)

Comment: @VividD: yeah, maybe I overgeneralized. But Sempervivum species are often similar, so one look like what is the most beautiful. For other genus, often it is not enough, OTOH because hybrids have different species, I would usually keep at large, so one don't miss new "varieties".

Answer (score 3):

It is a Sempervivum variety - they can look similar to Echeveria, but the latter never has the fine fringe of hairs around the edge of each leaf. As it's a Sempervivum, it is hardy in the zone you mention with one caveat - because it's in a small, individual pot it's more vulnerable to the soil freezing solid in very cold conditions, so it would be wise move the pot into a less exposed spot during winter.

As for the variety, well, there are thousands - there are online guides similar to the one in the link below for Sempervivum ID so you might find this one amongst those https://www.drought-smart-plants.com/sempervivum-picture-gallery.html